# Interactive pre-populated offline map for Cordova

Tags: cordova, dictionary, storage, offline, interactive

The goal is to have a fully pre-populated offline Interactive map inside a Cordova/phonegap project. Mapbox's '.mbtiles' seem to be a great approach as the tiles are stored simplistically inside one '.mbtiles' file.  However I haven't  seen HTML support or interactive support. Second to that is maps on a stick, however this seems to be a deprecated and more of a brut-approach. Are there any up to date approachs or good documentation on the subject?